How can I use a shader to make my brick wall look more realistic and have some color variation?
I have this brick wall in a project that I am working on. I modelled the wall itself in Blender: its a whole bunch of bricks which stick out a little from a cube that is meant to be the "mortar". The bricks themselves have their own material with the shader attatched, and the mortar also has its own material, no shader. I have attatched an image: The current brick wall
I want the bricks to have some more life to them, and to have the bricks not all be one color, something like this would be great: An idea of how I would like the wall to look.
I'd just like same random variation in the colors, but still keeping it looking normal (not hyper-realistic, just normal). I was thinking of using some type of noise for this but I honestly have no clue if that would work and how I could do it, so I figured I'd come on here for some ideas.
I also am very very new to shaders and a little clueless, so any and all help/advice/feedback would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance
Here is the shader code so far:
Shader "Custom/BrickShader"
{
    Properties
    {
        _BaseColor ("Base Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
        _BrickSize ("Brick Size", float) = 0.1
        _BrickSpacing ("Brick Spacing", float) = 0.02
    }
    SubShader
    {
        Tags { "RenderType"="Opaque" }
        LOD 100

        Pass
        {
            HLSLPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag

            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            struct appdata
            {
                float4 vertex : POSITION;
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
            };

            struct v2f
            {
                float4 sv_Position : SV_POSITION;
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
            };

            float _BrickSize;
            float _BrickSpacing;

            v2f vert (appdata v)
            {
                v2f o;
                o.sv_Position = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                o.uv = v.uv;
                return o;
            }

            fixed4 frag (v2f i) : SV_Target
            {
                // Calculate brick coordinates
                float brickX = floor(i.uv.x / (_BrickSize + _BrickSpacing));
                float brickY = floor(i.uv.y / (_BrickSize + _BrickSpacing));

                // Calculate brick offset within the brick
                float brickOffsetX = frac(i.uv.x / (_BrickSize + _BrickSpacing)) * _BrickSize;
                float brickOffsetY = frac(i.uv.y / (_BrickSize + _BrickSpacing)) * _BrickSize;

                // Simulate brick color using a simple pattern
                fixed4 brickColor = fixed4(0.568, 0.25, 0.21, 1); // Red brick color
                // if (brickOffsetX < _BrickSize * 0.2 || brickOffsetY < _BrickSize * 0.2)
                // {
                //         brickColor *= 0.8; // Darker color for edges
                // }

                return brickColor;
            }
            ENDHLSL
        }
    }
    FallBack "Diffuse"
}


You should look into Shader Graph. Way easier there to combine various layers of effects into a shader than writing the code for it yourself. Basically you want some randomness for the lines, a dirt layer and slight color variations + normal maps .. that's quite a lot to ask here ;)

Not proficient with shaders either, but if you want sth simple, you could get away with bump mapping. Find a tiling brick wall texture and its normal map and check here for the rest. There's a lot of info here on bump mapping as well. You could throw a material with albedo and normal maps on a cube and it'll look realistic, until you look at it closely or from the side when you realize it's fakery.

